# String index out of range: -2

Tags: java

For the following program am getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at Names.main(Names.java:33)
```

for line

```
System.out.println("The character at index 3 in "+middle+" is "+middle.substring(3, 1));
```

Do you see any problem in this line?

```
/* Names.java */

import java.io.*;

public class Names {

/** Performs various string operations on the name John Fitzgerald kennedy.
 *     
 * @param arg is not used
 */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "john";
        String middle = "Fitzgerald";
        String last = "Kennedy";
        String initials;
        String firstInit, middleInit, lastInit;

        firstInit = first.substring(0, 1);
        middleInit = middle.substring(0,1);
        lastInit = last.substring(0,1);
        initials = firstInit.concat(middleInit);
        initials = initials.concat(lastInit);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(first+" "+middle+" "+last+" ");
        System.out.println(initials);
        System.out.println(last+", "+first+" "+middle);
        System.out.println(last+", "+first+" "+middleInit+".");
        System.out.println(first.toUpperCase()+" "+last.toUpperCase());

        System.out.println(first+" equals john is "+first.equals("john"));
        System.out.println(first+" equals john (ignoring case is) "+first.equalsIgnoreCase("john"));
        System.out.println("The character at index 3 in "+middle+" is "+middle.substring(3, 1));
        System.out.println("The index of \"gerald\" within "+middle+" is "+middle.indexOf("gerald"));
        System.out.println("The index of \"gerald\" within "+last+" is "+last.indexOf("gerald"));

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Refer java docs. In Content assist also it says(int beginindex, in endindex);. How it will work backwards, LOok at the error its -2

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work:

```
middle.substring(3, 1)
```

You can't have an end value larger than your start value for [`String#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29%29):

> Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this String object, or **`beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`**.

Since you only want the character at index 3, use `charAt()` instead:

```
middle.charAt(3);
```

Or, using `substring` with a narrower range:

```
middle.substring(3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass *(start, end)* parameters to `substring`:

```
middle.substring(3, 4) // '4' since you just want one char
```

Remember that `substring()` won't return the char at index `4`.

**Note:**
A simpler way to do this would be using `charAt(index)`:

```
middle.charAt(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature is

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

So if you intend to take one character, you should use

```
middle.substring(3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)  by oracle, it is clear that subString() method will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Answer (score 0):

`middle.substring(from index , to index)` what your doing here `middle.substring(3, 1)` while using substring `to index greater than from index`

Study String Manipulation in Java